# need help to convert the time format from 07:32:23.436 to 07:32 am

Tags: php, time

im trying to change the format of `$row['event_time']`

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['school_id'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['score'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['teams'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['event'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['event_time'].'</td>';<----- this line of code im using PHP
echo '<td>'.$row['event_date'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: is $row coming from a database?

Comment: yes $row are from the database and i'm trying to format the time inline the table.

Comment: Can you show your database query? If it is MySQL try using DATE_FORMAT see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp for a simple examle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo '<td>' . date('h:i a', strtotime($row['event_time'])) . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert the string to a timestamp, then use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to display the date accordingly (refer to the section under *format* of the [parameters section](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) for more infomation about the format). See the example below, as well as [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mgwf-mqaq):

```
$row = array('event_time'=>'07:32:23.436'); //for demo purposes
$time = strtotime($row['event_time']);
echo 'time: '.$time.' date: '.date('h:i:s a',$time);
```